# Cloudflare SSL on Ec2

Tags: ssl, nginx, dns, mean, cloudflare

I bought SSL certificate from cloudflare. Now I need to activate https on my ec2 instance where I have MEAN stack application running with nginx.Also I've added cloudflare nameservers to my godaddy dns.The problem is that cloudflare didn't send me any certificates or keys, which I can attach to my nginx configs. Please tell me what is my next steps.Thanks for attention and for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL from cloudflare will terminate at Cloudflare itself. Either you can send http request from cloudflare to your ec2, or you can setup a selfsigned certificate on your ec2 and pin it at cloudflare or install letsencrypt on your ec2 for ssl.

Enduser -HTTPS-> cloudflare -HTTP-> your ec2

Comment: I've already solved this problem.Just copied certificate and key from cloudflare from crypto and added to nginx config and after that opened port 443 on both sides(on nginx and on ec2).Thanks for your time mdeora.